# XBAP WPF Application Unable to Access Settings Within app.config

Tags: wpf, web-services, app-config, xbap, appsettings

I have an XBAP WPF application that has been working for some time now. I am recently having problems accessing settings within the app.config.

Direct references to AppSettings return empty strings, and System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Count returns 0. Also, when trying to access a web service reference I get a "Could not find default endpoint element that references contract" error.

The app.config is copied to app.exe.config when running the application and there do not appear to be any differences.

Is anyone aware of any reason this might happen? The only change is that I have recently upgraded to a Windows 7 machine. Could I be missing a component? A colleague has run the same application on his machine with the same operating system with no problems.

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I have still not solved this problem. However, I am managing to work around it for now. The application only fails to access AppSettings when running it in the Visual Studio IDE. When I publish the application to a remote server, the app will run with no issues.